# XPATH - select/find next element in table after identifying text

Tags: xml, xpath, selenium

Sorry I am new to XPath & XML, but as I'm working in Selenium I need some help identifying elements by their XPath. As the content on the page I'm working for changes position I first need to select the top level by name - then subsequent sub menus by position...
(Sub menus are hidden until top level is clicked)

Example Menu

Sport1
     Venue 1
          Race 1
          Race 2
          Race 3
     Venue 2
          Race 1
          Race 2
          Race 3
Sport2
      Venue 1
          Race 1
          Race 2
      Venue 2
          Race 1
          Race 2

So far `//a[text()='Sport2']`   will select (and branch out) sports2 - wherever it is positioned in the menu.

and `//li[2]/ul/li[2]/ul/li[2]/a`  will select 2nd Sport, 2nd Venue then 2nd Race.

However what I need is to be able to select the Sport by text (as `//a[text()= 'Sports2']`) then select the second venue then second race...(i want to do these by position as the names change daily)

Which I am trying as `//a[text()= 'Sports2']/li[2]/ul/li[2]/a` (and does not work)

Any ideas?

Comment: Hi Treemonkey,I'm not the best with xml admittedly and its quite an advanced page....

However the following is a snippet from the top menu level (other sub menus are hidden till clicked) (see next post)

Comment: <div class="box links sidemenu">
     <h2><a href="/sport">Sports Betting</a></h2>
    
            <ul id="sportsNav">
        
            <li data-nodeId='50827.2' class='top'><a href='/sport?navitems=50827.2' onclick='return false;' >Today's Promotions</a></li>
        
            <li data-nodeId='16371.2' class='top'><a href='/sport?navitems=16371.2' onclick='return false;' >In-Play Schedule</a></li>

        
            <li data-nodeId='2.1' class='top'><a href='/sport?navitems=2.1' onclick='return false;' >Horse Racing</a></li>

Comment: As you haven't provided any XML document, the reason for the problem must be in the bad weather.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev guess your based in England also LOL :) /rain /rain /rain

Comment: @Treemonkey: No, I live near Seattle :)

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev Not much difference, then :-)

Comment: Please, put your tags in ` signs to make it `code`. As much I'd really like to help, I won't try to decode the html tags from plain text.

Answer (score 0):

Until there can be the html code seen clearly and easily, I can only give you the general advice:

If you're using `WebDriver` (Selenium 2), you can find an element, then call [findElement()](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#findElement%28org.openqa.selenium.By%29) on it - that will just search the underlying nodes, not the entire document:

```
WebElement elem = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()='Sport2']"));
elem.findElement(By.xpath("./something[something()]"));
```

If you're not, then maybe this (from the [XPath 1.0 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/)) will be helpful:

> The location path `//para[1]` does not mean the same as the location
>   path `/descendant::para[1]`. The latter selects the first descendant
>   `para` element; the former selects all descendant `para` elements that are
>   the first `para` children of their parents.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to utilise **FindElements** apposed to *FindElement* or *By.XPath* completely. The way you could do this (and by no means do I suggest it as the best way as it's rather messy and over-the-top) is to first zone in on the elements you want and then grab them all. To do this run your code as something like:

```
IWebElement sport2 = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[text()= 'Sports2']"));
ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> Venues = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//a[text()= 'Venue']"));
ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> Races = Venues[1].FindElements(By.XPath("//a[text()= 'Race']"));
// now you want Races[1]
```

Hope this helps! Though as others have said, html would facilitate for more efficient answers.